# Attach a static object to a robot link through a Gazebo world plugin

Tags: c++, plugins, robotics, gazebo-simu

I'm having some troubles making a World plugin for Gazebo simulator.

I have a robotic manipulator, which is in charge of picking up some boxes and move them in specific places. In order to simulate the grasping, I just want to rigidly attach the boxes (which are static models) to the robot end-effector, and detach them when they're in place.

I am not able to perform this simple task, though. I have found the `AttachStaticModel` function from the `physics::Model` class; I use it in this way:

```
robotModelPtr->AttachStaticModel(boxModelPtr, offset);
```

using as offset either `ignition::math::Pose3d()` or `boxLinkPtr->WorldPose() - robotLinkPtr->WorldPose()` but it does nothing.

Then, I tried to manually create a fixed joint between the box and the robot, as:

```
robotModelPtr->CreateJoint("connection", "fixed", robotLinkPtr, boxLinkPtr)
```

But doing this results in the box flying away.

The box SDF is made of a vision node and a collision node, both of them uses a .dae mesh.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use `AttachStaticModel` function. Anyway, for my purposes, I just created a world plugin that mantains pointers to the box's model and the robot end effector's link, and change the box's model position accordingly, at every Update event of the world.